# SQL errors when attempting to test Symfony 2 app - columns already exist, tables missing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, automated-tests

I'm following the test setup described [here](http://sgoettschkes.blogspot.com/2012/06/symfony2-test-database-best-pratice.html) and [also here](http://sgoettschkes.blogspot.de/2012/04/testclasses-for-symfony2.html).  When I attempt to run my tests, and the test db is in the process of being created, I get the following errors:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]
>   Schema-Tool failed with Error 'An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX deletedAtidx ON SurveyHash (deletedAt)':
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index deletedAtidx already exists' while executing DDL: CREATE INDEX deletedAtidx ON SurveyHash (deletedAt)
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableExistsException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX deletedAtidx ON SurveyHash (deletedAt)':
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index deletedAtidx already exists
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index deletedAtidx already exists
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index deletedAtidx already exists
>
> doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
>
> purging database
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>     An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM PageImage':
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: PageImage
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: PageImage
>
> doctrine:fixtures:load [--fixtures[="..."]] [--append] [--em="..."] [--purge-with-truncate]
>
> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException : An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.label AS label_1, t0.value AS value_2 FROM Setting t0 WHERE t0.label = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["webservice"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: Setting

Looking at my entities, the `deletedAt` index is *not* declared twice in my `SurveyHash` entity, and I have entities for both `PageImage` and `Setting`, yet those tables aren't being created, as verified by sqliteman.  Futher testing (see the comments in one of the answers below) show that it's throwing an error due to multiple tables using the same index name.

My `config_test.yml` has the following:

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
       driver: pdo_sqlite
       path: %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db
       charset: UTF8
   orm:
       auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
       auto_mapping: true
```

I'm a bit limited in the database info I can share due to a NDA, so I'm hoping these errors are a result of something in the links above or my `config_test.yml`.  I'm using Symfony 2.4.6, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that you're trying to do a `doctrine:schema:update` on tables where the datasets have foreign keys or you're trying to add multiple datasets.

What you could try is so to drop the database schema, recreate it and then refill it with the data.

So first do a `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force`, then `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` and then `doctrine:fixtures:load`.

I had the same issues and this works for me.

I just flown over the first link and what you're doing is to call `doctrine:schema:create` multiple times, which of course won't work because you've already created them. You only could `doctrine:schema:update --force` them or recreate with drop/create!

**ANSWER**

According to the comments below this Answer the Error was that he gave differnet indexes on different tables the same name, but the `names from index MUST be unique!`

Comment: Well, I tried manually dropping, and then creating the schema through the console, and ran into the same issue.  I can drop it, and it'll list that all the tables are dropped.  I can create the schema, but it only creates an *empty* test.db file.  When I run the update manually, it gives the same errors, and only creates 20 out of the 30 tables I need.  Removing the indexes removes the problem - no errors and all db tables created - but that's not really addressing the problem.  What's really weird is that it's a `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableException` which isn't listed in Doctrine 2.2's API

Comment: And like I said, I've gone over the offending entities, and none of their indexes are declared more than once.  So, it's just baffling that these errors appear.

Comment: What's really weird is that changing the names of the offending indexes also fixes it.  So, if I name one `deletedAtidx` in one table, then another `deletedAt_idx` in another, it works.  It's almost like it's forcing the `UNIQUE` constraint on the entire db, which AFAIK isn't how it's supposed to work.  It's possible to have unique indexes with the same name on multiple tables in the same db, correct?

Comment: No, taken from the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html): `Fields that are used for the index by feature HAVE to be unique in the database. The behavior for multiple entities with the same index-by field value is undefined.` So i'm guessing that not only the entity fields must be unique, also the indexes must me unique!

Comment: Yeah, it definitely looks like that's the case.  I have multiple entities with their `id` fields indexed, but I don't name them.  Looking at the SQL dump, it seems like the system gives them unique index names automatically.  It's only when I explicitly name them the same thing that the error occurs.  So, the solution is either don't name them, and let the system handle it, or be sure to name them different things.

Comment: Yeah, i tested it on my project where i also work with indexes. I named them different before just because it felt right for me, but i never thought about it. I tried it out with same names and got the same error! I'll just edit it in my answer so future readers don't have to search the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

It seams you have maybe duplicated your deletedAtidx. Search in your mapping config for it. 
If not, try to recreate the database (if you have no important data)

You should make work the command `doctrine:schema:create` before `doctrine:fixtures:load`

Try `doctrine:schema:update --force`