# Duplicate index on sqlite, not on mysql

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a entity definition that works on dev and production envs (mysql), but not on test (sqlite):

```
/**
 * Invoice
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoice", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="ref_idx", columns={"ref"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="created_at_idx", columns={"created_at"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="paid_idx", columns={"paid"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="is_valid_idx", columns={"is_valid"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="canceled_idx", columns={"canceled"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository")
 */
class Invoice
// [...]
```

When I run doctrine:schema:create or doctrine:schema:update --force on test env, I have the following error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                 
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX created_at_idx ON invoice (created_at)':  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index created_at_idx already exists                         


  [PDOException]                                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index created_at_idx already exists
```

Is someone already had this kind of issue? How to solve/ignore it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought. but one difference between the two DBMSs is that SQLITE is all text, all columns contain basically string data. Possible that you have some values  which are "different" in text but not in another format. Can't think if really great example, but like "123" and "0123" are different in text but not in an INT column.

Comment: I'm note sure to understand. You mean if I have another `created_at_ids` somewhere in another entity, sqlite can fail ?

Comment: Sorry! I answered for dupe rows and just realized from your comment that problem was dupe index itself. So yes, I believe if there's already an object called created_at_idx on the database, regardless of association with this table, it would fail. BUT that's going to be true for most DBMS so still not sure what would be your difference in behavior between the two DBMSs other than just a stray name. Look to see if one exists (I think is "SELECT * FROM my_db_name.sqlite_master where name = 'created_at_ids' "). Sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will investigate and wait for another help. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634713/1731473

In a nutshell, your index **must** have a unique name **across** your database.

So you can't have:

- invoice -> created_at_idx
- user -> created_at_idx

But:

- invoive -> invoice_created_at_idx
- user -> user_created_at_idx